# Good way to store formatted text in DB to output later

Tags: html, mysql, css

I write news for my website and format it like this:

```
[h1]News[h1]
[red]Happy New Year[/red]
[white]Happy New Year[/white]
```

The news are stored as is on the MySQL DB.
Then when it's called by my website, a function converts every code into HTML format.

```
[h1][/h1] = <h1></h1>
[red][/red] = <font color=red></font>
```

I'm not happy with this method for a long time, but now such codes are obsolet for HTML5.
Instead of using  I should add it to CSS.

I'm very beginner with PHP, MySQL, CSS, HTML...really, but I'm trying and learning.

So, what I need is the best solution for this matter.

I was thinking to create a CSS rule like:

```
span.news-red { color=red }
span.news-white { color=white }
```

And then  them into the code  for red text, etc...

Is this an effective solution or just a palliative?

Thank you.

## EDIT

I have this two functions to convert format of my text in order to be outputed for the visitor.

1st = Converts [white-text][/white-text] into

```
$string = preg_replace("/\[white-text\](\S+?)\[\/white-text\]/si","<font color=white>\\1</font>", $string);
```

2nd - Converts [url][/url] into

```
$string = preg_replace("/\[url\](\S+?)\[\/url\]/si","<a href=\"http://\\1\" target=\"_blank\">\\1</a>", $string);
```

Problems:
WHITE-TEXT - It only changes the color of one word phrases.

URL - It works fine, but I would like to be able to write anything in the readable part of the URL.

Comment: Bozdoz ... if you see my website code you would understand what I'm saying. What isn't old, is pretty horrible - e.g: I know that the best practice nowadays for MySQL is to use pdo, but I still do consults using the old way. That's why I ask if I'm doing this in the right way or if there is better ways to do this thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you want to have styles of text that are common. Give them descriptions as to why you are doing what you are doing. If I were you, I would name them something as to what they are in the db. Then let's say you decide that Red is just a horrible choice of colors. You could always change it to a different one very easily, just by editing the CSS.

Not knowing why you choose to make something red, I can't give you much of an answer, other than to try and use the css name that relates to why you chose red, rather than what you are doing in the first place.

Comment: Oh...there isn't a special reason for that, it's only to make the text looks good, instead of a monocolor...I use several colors (red, blue, green, orange, white, bold, underline, italic, etc)

Comment: If you are 100% positive you'll never change it, then go ahead and call it by color than. Otherwise...

Comment: Well ... thank you ... may I ask you another thing? This replaces a url into a clickable url - $ct = preg_replace("/\[url\](\S+?)\[\/url\]/si","<a href=\"http://\\1\" target=\"_blank\">\\1</a>", $ct); - I wanted to make the URL text independent, so I could write anything as text and it would still be replaced for the right URL...how could I do that?